# setAnimation vs startAnimation in android

Tags: android, animation, layout

I basically want to move a view from 1 location to another, plus I also want to increase its height gradually, So what should I use setAnimation or startAnimation.

```
TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -otherview.getHeight());
ta.setDuration(1000);
ta.setFillAfter(true);

myview.startAnimation(ta); //or, which one to use and what is the difference. 

myview.setAnimation(ta);
```

question: how to move this relative layout?

I tried `myview.scrollTo(x,y)` but no use.  Is it possible to gradually increase the view height gradually?

Answer (score 3):

This is my understanding.

SetAnimation

when the view is added to the viewGroup,animation will be called.when the view has been added,the animation will not be called

StartAnimation

animation will be called all the time even though the view has been added.