# Cant update item in custom adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, custom-adapter

im trying to add touchlistener for every item in listview.
here my code in my CustomAdapter for currentView (as i think)

```
rowView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        x1 = event.getX();
                       return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        x2 = event.getX();
                        float deltaX = x2 - x1;
                        if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                            if (x2 > x1) {
                                LEFT = false;
                                Logger.e("FALSE ");
                                txtTitle.setText("LEFT TO RIGHT");
                                moveLefttoRight = new TranslateAnimation(0, -150, 0, 0);
                                moveLefttoRight.setDuration(1500);
                                moveLefttoRight.setFillAfter(true);
                                swipeLayout.setAnimation(moveLefttoRight);
                                HomeChatAdapter.super.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                            else {
                                LEFT = true;
                                Logger.e("TRUE");
                                txtTitle.setText("RIGHT TO LEFT");
                                moveLefttoRight = new TranslateAnimation(0, -150, 0, 0);
                                moveLefttoRight.setDuration(1500);
                                moveLefttoRight.setFillAfter(true);
                                swipeLayout.setAnimation(moveLefttoRight);

                            }

                        } else {
                            CLICKITEM = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

problem with animation and view.setText("blabla")
When my swipe is done "from left to right or from right to left" 
no changes on screen
If i move out 
txtTitle.setText("LEFT TO RIGHT");

```
                        moveLefttoRight = new TranslateAnimation(0, -150, 0, 0);
                        moveLefttoRight.setDuration(1500);
                        moveLefttoRight.setFillAfter(true);
                        swipeLayout.setAnimation(moveLefttoRight);
```

this part of code from TouchListener - than all ok but its work one time when created.
Can any help me how to do solution in this situation ?
Just want to move item in listview to left or right . Regard Peter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to use

```
swipeLayout.startAnimation(...);
```

instead.

According to [setAnimation vs startAnimation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909865/setanimation-vs-startanimation-in-android/10910033) :

> setAnimation
>
> Sets the next animation to play for this view.But view animation does
>   not start yet.
>
> startAnimation
>
> If you want the animation to play immediately, use startAnimation.
>   This method provides allows fine-grained control over the start time
>   and invalidation, but you must make sure that
>
> 1) the animation has a start time set,
>
> 2) the view will be invalidated when the animation is supposed to
>   start.