# How to achieve this effect in Snackbar

Tags: android, animation, material-design, snackbar

Here is the gif:
[image]

There are several features:

- Fade in and immediately out.
- It has margin. Because the default effect is match parent width.

Now I have already solved the margin problem. But I don't know how to achieve the animation effect. And here's my code:

snackbar_animation.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="500"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:shareInterpolator="true">

<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.1"
    android:toAlpha="1" />

<scale
    android:fromXScale="0.5"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1"
    android:toYScale="1"/>

</set>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private Button snackbar;
private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.snackbar_test);

    coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinator);

    snackbar = findViewById(R.id.show_snackbar);
    snackbar.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.show_snackbar:
            showSnackbar();
            break;
    }
}

private void showSnackbar(){
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout,"i am a snack bar",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);

    View sbView = snackbar.getView();

    // add animation
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.snackbar_animation);
    sbView.setAnimation(animation);

    // modify margin
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) sbView.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(params.leftMargin + 50,
            params.topMargin,
            params.rightMargin + 50,
            params.bottomMargin + 50);

    sbView.setLayoutParams(params);

    // show snackbar
    snackbar.show();
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/show_snackbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="show snackbar" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If there are something else I need to know about this question, just comment below this question.such as: value animation or other things.I am new to the animation, so if you know the great learning materials, tell me, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909865/setanimation-vs-startanimation-in-android). `setAnimation()` just queues an animation. It doesn't actually start anything. SnackBar doesn't call `startAnimation` when it's show, either.

However, even if you use `startAnimation()`, your code probably won't work as-is. You need to initially set the scale of your SnackBar to 0, so it's at the proper starting value.

You should use `SnackBar#setCallback()` and then start your show animation inside the `onShow()` method. Set your dismiss animation inside the `onDismiss()` method.

Comment: Actually, `setAnimation()` also work. What confuse me is that how the effect done with animation xml.Because snackbar has default animation from bottom to top, but now, the effect i want is fade in.