# Shake animation does not appear on the app

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new in android. So I tried to apply shake animation for wrong answers in a quiz app. But it does not work. I also checked similar questions on this website but I could not find my
mistake on my code. In terms of syntax, I guess everything is correct. Could you please help me on this?

'''

```
package com.example.trivaapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.trivaapp.data.Repository;

import com.example.trivaapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import com.example.trivaapp.model.Question;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

List<Question> questionArrayList;

ActivityMainBinding binding;
int questionNumber = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    questionArrayList = new Repository().getQuestionList(az ->{

        binding.questionText.setText(az.get(questionNumber).getAnswer());

        binding.QuestionNumber.setText(questionNumber + "/" + az.size());
    });
    binding.trueButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {

        if(true == questionArrayList.get(questionNumber).isTruenswer()){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.correct, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.incorrect, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ShakeAnimation();
        }
    });

    binding.falseButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {

        if(false == questionArrayList.get(questionNumber).isTruenswer()){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.correct, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.incorrect, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ShakeAnimation();
        }
    });
}

private void ShakeAnimation() {
    Animation shakeAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.shake);
    binding.cardView.setAnimation(shakeAnimation);
}

public void Next(View view) {
    questionNumber = (questionNumber < questionArrayList.size()) ? ++questionNumber : questionNumber;


    binding.questionText.setText(questionArrayList.get(questionNumber).getAnswer());

    binding.QuestionNumber.setText(questionNumber + "/" + questionArrayList.size());
}
    }
```

'''

My shake.xml code:

'''

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="150"
    android:fromDegrees="-10"
    android:pivotX="10%"
    android:pivotY="10%"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toDegrees="10"
/>
```

Comment: first post on SO in google on SetAnimation query answers your question.
use startAnimation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setAnimation vs startAnimation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909865/setanimation-vs-startanimation-in-android)

Comment: Yes, but I still have not got what is the point to use setAnimation() if it will not demonstrate anything on the screen. I mean when do we need to use setAnimation().

Comment: ok. I will add an aswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every android `View` has a protected property `mCurrentAnimation`. You can use methods `setAnimation`, `getAnimation` and `clearAnimation` to access this property and attach/detach animation to a view. Generally, аnimation wont start playing if you just set it.

Let's check `startAnimation` code:

```
        public void startAnimation(Animation animation) {
            animation.setStartTime(Animation.START_ON_FIRST_FRAME);
            setAnimation(animation);
            invalidateParentCaches();
            invalidate(true);
        }
```

You see? It sets start time for your animation to run next frame (immediately), attaches animation to a view with `setAnimation` method and calls invalidate (ask android to redraw this view). Without invalidate, animation could not start.

P.S. This is an old API for animation. Check android dev site for up to date API.

Comment: Now, I got everything. I am really grateful for your help. Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: @YadigarYusifov good luck with your journey )